# List of network accounts doesn't include display name in each link

Tags: bug, user-accounts, network-profile

I'm pretty sure it used to, but no longer does. When viewing my [list of network accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/89201/animuson?tab=accounts), none of the profile URLs for each site except for Area 51 include the display name at the end of the URL. This results in a redirect to happen every time you visit a new site, as it will append the name onto the URL as it should be there.

Curiously, there is a `/` at the end of the URL which would indicate it expects something after the URL. Perhaps the system is borking and failing to load the display name properly?

I've tested this on several profiles and the results are the same. The issue also occurs in the Accounts box on the per-site profile page.

Comment: I don't recall the network page ever showing display names. And I'm quite sure the per-site profile never did.